# How do I increase the number of these values in Notepad++?

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have these "bac entries" here and where their id at the end, I want to change every single id by adding a number to them, for example BacEntry idx="21" would become BacEntry idx="22" or BacEntry idx="121" (increasing by 1 or 100) so how do I do that?

Heres the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkPVr.png

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML-aware tool. For example, I happen to maintain [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), in which you could write

```
open file.xml ;
for //BacEntry set @idx (@idx + 1) ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but can you further explain? I've been trying to "install" xsh for 2 hours.

Comment: @YAKgamer: XSH is written in Perl and uses its [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) which you need installed. Its recent versions install the underlying libxml2 themselves, for the older ones you need libxml2 development files, too.

Comment: The normal way to install it would be to run `cpan install XML::XSH2`, it should install all the dependencies, too.

Comment: oh my god im so sorry, i had forgotten to install perl and stupidly tried to run the command, sorry and thanks.